# Which graphing library does Stack Exchange use?

Tags: support, design, graphs

Viewing reputation changes on Stack Overflow produces a nice graph which can be 'zoomed in' on to view more detailed reputation changes, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470184/user470184?tab=reputation&sort=graph). Is this using a library or is it custom written? If it's a library, which is it?

Comment: Looks like highcharts on the reputation tab - http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: @Oliver: <s>have you tried to compare *layout*? They look slightly similar indeed, but the implementations are cardinally different. Highchart's one is svg-based, and SO's is pure html</s>. Oh wow, I haven't seen reputation page yet before :-S sorry, I was wrong

Comment: @zerkms The rep graph does use SVG elements, so you're partly right there.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) because inspecting the DOM reveals stuff such as:

```
<svg ...>
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
  ...
  <g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1">
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 2 reputation graphs,

I think the one you are referring is the the graph in reputation tab.
The graph in reputation tab is rendered using highcharts in fact it is a master-detail type of chart.

While coming to the other one in the summary tab, its a html graph not a highcharts one.

Comment: True, the small graph appears to be totally static, created on the server side.